# Return value is not (quote <value>)

Tags: testing, clojure, quote

I'm trying out the challenges on [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) and am getting stuck on the following code

```
(ns com.koddsson.for-clojure
  (:use [clojure.test :only [is deftest run-tests]]))

(defn my-flatten
  ([x] (if (not (and (seq? x) (vector? x)))
           x                      ; If x is not a sequence nor a vector
           (map my-flatten x))))  ; else recursivly apply the flatten function

(deftest test28
  (is (= (my-flatten '((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]])) '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (is (= (my-flatten ["a" ["b"] "c"]) '("a" "b" "c")))
  (is (= (my-flatten '((((:a))))) '(:a))))

(run-tests)
```

It generates the following output.

```
λ bubblegum 20 → λ git master* → lein exec -p 28.clj

Testing com.koddsson.for-clojure

FAIL in (test28) (28.clj:10)
expected: (= (my-flatten (quote ((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]))) (quote (1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  actual: (not (= ((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]) (1 2 3 4 5 6)))

FAIL in (test28) (28.clj:11)
expected: (= (my-flatten ["a" ["b"] "c"]) (quote ("a" "b" "c")))
  actual: (not (= ["a" ["b"] "c"] ("a" "b" "c")))

FAIL in (test28) (28.clj:12)
expected: (= (my-flatten (quote ((((:a)))))) (quote (:a)))
  actual: (not (= ((((:a)))) (:a)))

Ran 1 tests containing 3 assertions.
3 failures, 0 errors.
```

It seems that it's giving the right return value but in the wrong format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test output actually shows that you are *not* getting the right return value.

```
FAIL in (test28) (28.clj:10)
expected: (= (my-flatten (quote ((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]))) (quote (1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  actual: (not (= ((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]) (1 2 3 4 5 6)))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  output of my-flatten
```

You should verify in the REPL that your `my-flatten` returns the marked output above. Indeed, your function is essentially the identity function.

There are three things wrong with your code as written.

1. The condition `(and (seq? x) (vector? x))` is never true. Hover over spoiler.

   > You should either change the `and` to an `or` or use `sequential?` instead.
2. With the above fixed, your structure will now be changed into a structure of sequences due to `map` returning sequences. These sequences need to be concatenated recursively. Hover over spoiler.

   > Change `map` to `mapcat`
3. Now the code is temporarily broken. You need to protect the base case from the action of the concatenation. Hover over spoiler.

   > wrap the base case return value `x` in a collection, e.g. `[x]`.

Comment: Thank you so much A. Webb! I for some reason thought the right hand side value was the output I was getting from my function :)